# How can I change the color of  the browser content field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am attaching bitmap field in title  and  bitmap field in status .

and i add a field which have a browser content

```java
browserContent = BE._renderingSession.getBrowserContent(connection, this, e);

if (browserContent != null) {

     Field field = browserContent.getDisplayableContent();

     if (field != null) {
          synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
               add(field);
          }
     }
}
```

when the browser content loading their color is black and after loading they are fine.

My problem is that i did't want their color to be black ,... it should be white while they are loading...

Comment: Try setting a white background on `field`.

Comment: @Rupak, how do you do that, though?  You don't have access to the class that `field` is an instance of.  You can't extend it and override `paint()`.  What call would you actually use to change its background color?

Comment: @Nate, you can use the method `setBackground()` [as `browserContent.getDisplayableContent()` is casted as `Field`], api link http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setBackground%28net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Background%29

Comment: @Rupak.  Yep, that works.  Sorry.  The old BrowserSession example code I had wasn't originally working with `setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE))` ... but, it was for a completely unrelated reason (bug in my code).  You should add that as the answer ... I'll upvote.